# SQL Query Returning Image

Tags: microsoft-word, sql

We are trying to get a sql query to return an image.

This is a web based application that generates a letter (in word) where we have this element configured in a store template.

We have tried the following as SQL query (returning XML) and SQL query (single value)

```
Declare @htmlBody nvarchar(4000)
SET @htmlBody = '<' + 'img src="URL/Logo.jpg"' + '/>'
SELECT @htmlBody as CompanyHeaderLogo
```

When the letter is produced it pulls through an image icon but displays as a red x.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: hit F12 in your browser, go to the network tab, and determine what the actual value of the img src= attribute is, and confirm that there is an image file at that url.

Comment: hi, it is the same location as we have in the sql query, but still returns as a red x.

Comment: I mean the fully qualified url to the image starting with http://.../... Then Paste that url into a browser. does the image come up? if the browser is showing a red X then it is unable to download the image from the url provided.

Comment: try this SET @htmlBody = '<img src=' + '"' + 'URL/Logo.jpg' + '"' + ' />'